# Is there a way to transform the foreach loop into wp_query?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I'm loading the items straight from the database with php foreach loop, but i want to use wp_query loop, because that gives me more control about pagination, and max items on page.

I tried to transform the code into wp_query loop but not with a good result. What can i do?

```
<?php 
global $wpdb;
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "kv_beoordelingen";
$beoordelingen = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM `{$table_name}`  \n". "ORDER BY `{$table_name}`.`dateSince` DESC LIMIT 42");                         
if( $beoordelingen ) {

    foreach ( $beoordelingen as $beoordeling ) {

        //vars
        $beschrijving = $beoordeling->description; 
        ?>

            <?php
            $beoordeling_query = new WP_Query(array(
            'post_type' => $beoordeling,
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'order'     => 'DESC',
            'orderby' => 'date',
            'paged' => get_query_var('paged'))); ?>

            <?php if ( $beoordeling_query->have_posts() ) : ?>

                    <?php while ( $beoordeling_query->have_posts() ) : $beoordeling_query->the_post();
                        if( $beschrijving ) {
                            echo "<p><strong>Ervaring</strong><br/> ".$beschrijving." </p>";                
                        }                                                   
                    endwhile; ?>            

                    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
                </div>  
            <?php endif; ?
<?php };

} else {
    echo "Geen beoordelingen beschikbaar";
} ?>
```

Comment: First of all, _show us_ what you actually tried.

Comment: I just updated the code i tried ;-)

Comment: You don’t necessarily need to replace the foreach loop, if you use `WP_Query::get_posts()` to get the current result set as an array, you should be able to keep that loop more or less as-is. `WP_Query` can still handle the rest of the pagination logic. But if you want to do it using classic WP “the loop” functionality, the basic principle is explained in many places, such as https://digwp.com/2011/05/loops/#wp-query

Comment: @misorude Allright, i can just use the foreach loop instead of the WP_Query. But how about pagination with foreach loop?

Comment: Why do you have _two_ loops now, that makes rather little sense. You need to make your query / get the result from it _before_ the foreach loop. And the pagination can be handled independently of the loop.

Comment: Because i don't know how this piece works. I hope somebody can explain to me what i am doing wrong and give a code example how it should work.

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/254199/pagination-when-using-wp-query, https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/120407/how-to-fix-pagination-for-custom-loops